# How can I adjust the height of my mat-table so that it fills the remaining vertical space and any excess is scrollable?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I've added an image below which better details the model of my webpage.

I have a page that is a part of my Angular application. Within the application I have a mat-card, and within that card is a mat-table which may display a long list of data.

The list of data sometimes causes the height of the mat-card to be extended past the lower boundary of the page, and since the page isn't scrollable there is an amount of rows that will be unaccessible by the user.

I want to be able to fix the size of the mat-card to be the height of the page minus the height of the header, so that the mat-card fills all of the remaining vertical space on the page.

We're making use of bootstrap, so the mat-card is contained inside of a col-8 class.

Is there a way that I can set the height of the card to be the remaining height on the page, and then cause any overflow within the body of the table to be scrollable?

I've attempted to set overflow-y on the mat-table to scroll, but all that happens is the scrollbar appears but doesn't offer the ability to actually scroll.

The issue here is that the height of the mat-card varies, so if the container holding the table is `height: 100%`, it'll take up as much height as it requires to display the full length of the table. I need to force the card height to only take up the visible available height, and not the height it needs to display the table. Something like `height: 100% available width`

[image]

Comment: try `flex: 1` with `min-height: 0` and on the parent set `display: flex; overflow: auto`

Comment: @BlindDespair Is this on the card or table?

Comment: try adding `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` to table and please post the code here

Comment: Could you reproduce at [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @Jake12342134 if you share the code it would be easier to tell.

Comment: @Jake12342134 card should be `display: flex; overflow: auto`, table should be `flex: 1; min-height: 0`, but it will only work if your card is already filling the space.

Comment: I've added a div around my table, as the card contains more than just the table. I now have, `<div class="table-container">
        <table class="data-table"
        mat-table
        [dataSource]="snip"
      ></table>` with your css but this hasn't changed anything.

Comment: try to wrap that mat-table in another div and set `flex: 1; min-height: 0` and then put `min-height: 100%` on the table. It's hard to tell how exactly to make it work, without trying it out.

Comment: @BlindDespair You've lost me, can you post some code and show me what you mean? Wrap the table in a div, and that div in another div?

Comment: OK I'll try to do it when I get to my laptop

Comment: This was working for me.....:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-ahzyc4?file=app%2Fapp.component.css).
As I wrote in the comments you can have your content container being `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, then you card would be `flex: 1; min-height: 0; overflow: auto` and you can then make your table: `min-height: 100%`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is what I'm looking for. If I give the example-container class a `height: 600px`, this gives the correct behaviour i.e. the table becomes scrollable. But I only want this to happen when the table-container exceeds the height of the screen. I don't want to have to provide a fixed height for the table container.

Comment: It seems as though the answer to this problem is probably not as hard as we think. If I set my mat-table's container to have a fixed max-height and set the overflow to auto, I get the behaviour I want. All I need to do is make it so that the container's height fills the rest of the available vertical space. That can't be hard to do, surely?

Comment: As I said you can achieve that with `flex: 1; min-height: 0`, but I need to see your code to tell for sure where to do it. If you fork my answer and do it closer to your example, I will surely help you.

Comment: I'm struggling to recreate an example due to the code being far more complex than my example. But you still aren't understanding. I'll draw another diagram.

Comment: Please check here: https://imgur.com/a/02Lrv9E

The table should only take up as much space as required to display the rows, up until the bottom of the card (+ page) is reached, at which point the table should become scrollable

Comment: Yes, I understand, please check my example again. I think it looks like what you need now. Of course to achieve this in real world you have to make sure that all your parent elements somehow have height set. I will never work with a dynamic height. So event if you want to have 100% you still need to specify that all the way and then my solution will work. It's just how css works with heights. To check that table becomes scrollable you can uncomment some table entries in `app.component.ts` in the example I sent.

Comment: So since I am using an Angular app and this is deep in the application code it's unlikely I'll be able to specify the height property of every parent element. Would there be an alternative way to allow this behaviour to happen?

Comment: It depends on how your app is built now exactly... Thing is that if you want to stretch your component you have to base it on parent's height, if you want height to build up based on children's height, then you have to specify it manually. Unfortunately it cannot same time build up height based on children and grow to fill page, I mean, with that css that I wrote it can, but you have to make sure that parent already has that space available.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll mark your answer as correct as I'm sure it'll help me to eventually reach the correct solution.

Comment: is your solution still working because it didn't work on my case 
my mat table stil lrender out of the screen